# Timeout ao usar httr:POST()

Tags: r, post, httr

Caros,

Estou tentando fazer uma conferência de registros no [site do CREA-RS](http://apolo.crea-rs.org.br/apoloaplsrv01/servlet/org.crears.apolo.prod.hsel_profis_consulta_site?,0), mas todas as vezes esta dando o seguinte erro:

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Timeout was reached
```

Alguem sabe o que pode estar acontecendo? O R está conectando normal a internet. Segue o código que estou tentando rodar:

```
b2 <- "http://apolo.crea-rs.org.br/apoloaplsrv01/servlet/org.crears.apolo.prod.hsel_profis_consulta_site?,0"
r <- POST(b2, encode = 'form', body = list("_PRF_NROCPF"  = 12345678910))
```

Comment: Aqui rodou normal... Você fez muitas consultas? Será que seu IP foi bloqueado?

Comment: Deu erro já na primeira, e pelo navegador eu consigo entrar no site

Comment: Você tem algum firewall? Outros códigos de webscrapping funcionam aí?

Comment: Sim, funcionam. `readLines(b2)` funciona também.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O pacote httr, por alguma razão, não utiliza a configuração de proxy do computador. Para resolver, é preciso carregar o pacote [devtools](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/devtools/index.html) e chamar a seguinte função:

```
set_config(use_proxy(url="IP/URL DA PROXY", port=PORTA DA PROXY))
```